# Java Android. Как вызвать метод с непонятным параметром. android.location.Location

Tags: java, android, android-location

Только начинаю изучать Java, во многом путаюсь и не понимаю. Вопрос скорее всего, очень глупый, но разобрать никак не могу, очень прошу объяснить.

Делаю приложение для Android в Android Studio. Хочу по нажатии на кнопку получить местоположение (широту и долготу). Использую android.location.Location.
Моя программа выглядит примерно так:

```
public class MyProgram extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView MyTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyTextView);
    }

    public void MyButton(View text_info) {
        MyTextView.setText("Привет!");
    }
}
```

У меня есть ещё один класс (MyClass), где я прописываю свой метод для определения местоположения, вот сам метод:

```
public static String My_Location(Location loc) {
    LAT = loc.getLatitude();
    LON = loc.getLongitude();
    LOCATION = LAT + ", " + LON;
    return LOCATION;
}
```

Так вот, теперь я хочу обратиться к этому методу из своего основного класса, вызвать его по нажатии на кнопку и вывести результат на экран, то есть как-то так:

```
public void MyButton(View text_info) {
    MyTextView.setText("Текущее местоположение: " + MyClass.My_Location(???));
}
```

Собственно вопрос: что мне передавать методу в качестве параметра (вместо ???). В других случаях, когда параметры моего метода были типа "Context", я передавала туда "this", и это работало, здесь же такое не прокатило. 
Подскажите, что же там нужно передавать или может быть такое вообще реализуется совсем по-другому?

Comment: Когда вы передавали `this` и всё прокатывало, конструктор (или другой метод) требовал переменную типа `Context`. Сейчас он просит переменную типа `Location`, подробнее об этом [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2985340).

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что просит переменную типа Location, но не понимаю что ему передать в качестве этой переменной, ведь я хочу определить местоположение, а не установить его, иначе говоря, мне нечего передать, я наоборот хочу получить

Comment: Тогда, думаю, [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227299) ответ вам подойдёт. Нужно быть внимательнее с разрешениями.

Comment: Спасибо! Пока что получаю null вместо координат, но продвижения уже есть, буду разбираться дальше